# Azure Elastic Job Delete

Tags: sql, database, azure, elasticsearch, jobs

How do i delete my Elastic Job Agent. 
i do have made jobs at it, just create it.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, does the problem solved now?

Answer (score 1):

If you create the Elastic Job Agent by T-SQL, please reference [Delete a job and all its job history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/elastic-jobs-tsql#delete-a-job-and-all-its-job-history):

**Delete a job and all its job history**

```
--Connect to the job database specified when creating the job agent

EXEC jobs.sp_delete_job @job_name='ResultsPoolsJob'

--Note: job history is automatically deleted if it is >45 days old
```

For PowerShell, please reference [Remove-AzSqlElasticJobAgent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/remove-azsqlelasticjobagent?view=azps-3.3.0#description):

```
Remove-AzSqlElasticJobAgent
      [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
      [-ServerName] <String>
      [-Name] <String>
      [-Force]
      [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
      [-WhatIf]
      [-Confirm]
      [<CommonParameters>]
```

You also can delete it from `Elastic Job Agent Preview` on Portal:
[image]

To get more details, you could read this blog: [Introduction to Azure Elastic Database Jobs](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5665/introduction-to-azure-elastic-database-jobs/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not to delete the Elastic Pool Job, its to delete the SQL DB that have been connected to he job, the fault is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBehf.png)